# How can I fix my $PATH variable?

Tags: macos, bash

I need to revert my $PATH back to the default.

The catch here is that I broke it so bad that the `echo $PATH` command returns: `/usr/`
that's it, which means I can't use any of the methods described in other answers basically because any command returns "unknown command".

I can't vi, I can't nano, I can't do squat over Terminal. All of that was working before I broke $PATH so I'm sure its all path related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends how you changed your path.

- If you changed it in your shell, just close the window and open a new shell.
- If you changed it in a profile, change it there.

Your path should look something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Comment: And `export` is a shell builtin, so you can simply restore PATH to a saner state with `export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` (If you're a tcsh user, `setenv PATH …` would be the equivalent).

Comment: @Camila Per your edit in reply, I'm a bit confused — it didn't work? Could you clarify?